# Is it possible to affirm there is pseudoreplication in a design without making assumption on variable importance?

Tags: anova, experiment-design, importance, blocking, pseudorepliction

this is quite an abstract question, but I am trying to learn more of the basics in pseudoreplication.

Pseudo replication is defined by [Hurlbert (1984)](https://www.uvm.edu/%7Engotelli/Bio%20264/Hurlbert.pdf) as:

> Pseudoreplication may be defined , in analysis of variance terminology, as the testing for treatment effects with an error term inappropriate to the hypothesis being considered.

It seems to me that whenever someone is stating that an model is pseudoreplicating, he/she is making an assumption about the importance of each variable in the model.

For example, I'm taking an example from [Gotteli](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/a-primer-of-ecological-statistics-9781605350646?cc=us&lang=en&#:%7E:text=Gotelli%20and%20Aaron%20M.,Ellison&text=A%20Primer%20of%20Ecological%20Statistics%2C%20Second%20Edition%2C%20explains%20fundamental%20material,for%20ecologists%20and%20environmental%20scientists.) (a primer of ecological statistics) of a split plot design. In this design the researcher is measuring number of baby barnacles as a result in 3 treatments of predation (Unmanipulated, Control, Predator exclusion and predator inclusion) and in 3 treatments of plataform (cement, granite,slate). The research needed cages to make the first treatment, but did not had enough. So he grouped one sample from each kind of substrate in a cage, and this cages shared a predation treatment. He then spread cages randomly in the environment.

Something of this shape but with more replicates; Each color is a treatment.

[image: example of split plot design]

Now if you are using this grouping, the book recommends an ANOVA with the two treatments plus a "block" factor nested within the predator treatment.

Not following this design, for example treating this example as 2-way factorial ANOVA would be pseudoreplicating.

However, to me it seems equally valid to group samples by platform treatment (circle colors in the picture).

The only reason we shouldn't is because we have to group samples in such a way to maximize differences between blocks, and we **believe** samples that are closer to each other should be more similar than samples that are very far away and share the same treatment. This is very likely to be true, but it is a belief nonetheless. It might be possible that those samples are more similar to one another than to the ones they share a cage with. We might only get a satisfactory answer after running the experiment and seeing the effect of each variable.

Is this reasoning correct? Is pseudoreplication in the eye of the beholder and its set of beliefs about the world?